# Traffic from one interface to another (wlp3s0b1 > ppp0) on port 8080 and 5000

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu

I searched a lot for a solution and found 50 similar questions. I have tried most of them but could not make this work.

In short:

- Wireless interface (192.168.0.18)
- 3G dongle interface (10.249.143.9)

I can access java app (tomcat) via 127.0.0.1:8080 or 192.168.0.18:8080 and it works, but i need requests from java app go thru the 3G dongle (ppp0).

Java app scan / read other devices via port 5000 on same network like ppp0 (IP Addresses 10.249.143.2 - 10.249.143.50)

This all works if I disconnect my wifi network, but when I reconnect to wifi it all stops working because 192.168.0.18 can't reach devices from IP Addresses 10.249.143.2 - 10.249.143.50

With wifi connected:

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp3s0b1 proto dhcp metric 600 
default dev ppp0 proto static scope link metric 700 
10.64.64.64 dev ppp0 proto kernel scope link src 10.249.143.9 
10.64.64.64 dev ppp0 proto kernel scope link src 10.249.143.9 metric 700 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp3s0b1 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlp3s0b1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.19 metric 600
```

Without wifi:

```
default dev ppp0 proto static scope link metric 700 
10.64.64.64 dev ppp0 proto kernel scope link src 10.249.143.9 
10.64.64.64 dev ppp0 proto kernel scope link src 10.249.143.9 metric 700
```

Comment: Could you you edit your question and add the output of `ip route show` with and without wifi connection?

Comment: I edit post. I hope you ask for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, see that there are no explicit routes to `10.249.143.0/24` (I'm making up the mask, I don't what it is).

That means that packets going to that network will follow the default route. When wifi is up, the default route is over `wlp3s0b1`, when wifi is down the default route is over `ppp0`.

You could add an explicit route to the `10.249.143.0/24` network. For example, as `root`, this should do it:

```
# ip route add 10.249.143.0/24 dev ppp0
```

Now, it does not matter is wifi is up or down, because you have told the system how to route packages going to that network.

Comment: Thank you very much, it work from first try :) I will now just block all ports except 5000 on ppp0 interface. Can i use GUFW or UFW to to do that?

Comment: Can you please tell howto save ip route, for permanently use.